# Fix a layout above soft keyboard

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I know this question has been on the internet for ages, but nothing seems to work in my case.

**What's wrong**

[image] [image]

As seen in screenshots, the layout having the spinner is not pushed up and is overlapped by the soft keyboard. I want this layout to be placed just above the keyboard when it pops up.

**My layout file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="believe.cht.speak.MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="64dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_bubble"
        android:tint="@color/blue" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:gravity="top|start"
        android:hint="Start typing..."
        android:padding="8dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/shadow"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="6dp"
        android:src="@drawable/shadow" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/spinnerLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@color/blue">

        <Spinner

            android:id="@+id/spinner"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**What I've tried**

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"

android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" //in the manifest, also tried combining the two

getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN); //in the activity

<item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item> //in styles.xml
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/logo"
            android:layout_width="64dp"
            android:layout_height="64dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_message" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:gravity="top|start"
            android:hint="Start typing..."
            android:padding="8dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/shadow"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="6dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_camera" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/spinnerLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

            <Spinner

                android:id="@+id/spinner"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**Manifest file**

```
    <activity android:name=".MyActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image] [image]

Comment: You made my day! I tried nesting my layout in a ScrollView too but didn't use the `android:fillViewport` thing which made the layout to collapse because of `android:layout_weight="1"`

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Nilesh's answer above, even though the code worked, it didn't work with my Java class. The reason was that I was hiding the statusbar with

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Using the code provided and leaving the statusbar untouched did the job. Don't know why. I would be helpful if anyone could explain this.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a RelativeLayout instead of LinearLayout and add `android:alignParentBottom="true"` to your `spinnerLayout`

Comment: I made this layout originally using RelativeLayout only, and tried this too, no luck. The answer above did the job.